# Authentication failed: password does not match stored value (see update 2)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my current spring project, I have the following security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="com.spring.loja")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        web.expressionHandler(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/erro/**", "/categoria/**", "/produto/**", "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/entrar").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
                .failureUrl("/entrar?erro=login").permitAll()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/erro/403")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
            .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

When I run the application and try login in it, the system return to the login page, even with the right login credencials (I am sure of it).

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I also try this, with the same problem. Seems to me this configuration can't reach my userDetailsService class, which should be retrieve through the autowired property in this class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="com.spring.loja")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        web.expressionHandler(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/erro/**", "/categoria/**", "/produto/**", "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/entrar").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
                .failureUrl("/entrar?erro=login").permitAll()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/erro/403")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
            .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return auth.getOrBuild();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

After configure log4j, I found the error was the password not matching stored value. The problem is that I make sure the password stored in the database was encoded as MD5, and my PasswordEncoder bean is this:

```
@Component
public class BCryptPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence arg0) {
        try {
            return getMD5Hex((String) arg0);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return "NoSuchAlgorithmException";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence arg0, String arg1) {
        return arg0.equals(encode(arg1));
    }

    public static String getMD5Hex(final String inputString) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(inputString.getBytes());

        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        return convertByteToHex(digest);
    }

    private static String convertByteToHex(byte[] byteData) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

where I explicity tell I want use MD5. What's wrong here?

ps.: I notice too the application aren't using my authenticationManager bean, defined in the SEcurityConfig class (the second listing in the question)

Comment: can you provide debug logs for spring security ?

Comment: @coder what you suggest to get them?

Comment: at present you have any logging configured in your app ?

Comment: @coder no, I try log4j once, but can't get to set it to my system.

Comment: @coder after configure log4j, I discover that my problem was password don't matching with the stored value. My problem is that I am sure the stored value is encoded with MD5. I just update the question to include my PasswordEncoder. DO you can tell what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder matches method have signature

```
boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword);
```

So it means arg0 is the password entered by user and arg1 is your encoded password saved in DB.
So the implementation should be

```
 public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
            return encodedPassword.equals(encode(rawPassword));
 }
```

You are encoding the encoded password again in matches method, as you are using incorrect sequence of arguments.
Its a good practice to use meaningful names instead of arg0, arg1, to avoid confusion.